# AngularJS error when i am showing the user

Tags: angularjs

I am creating a task manager but when i show the name of the user the administrator cannot modify the tasks from the users like an user:

The function to obtain the tasks its:

```
$scope.get = function(){
        var user = $stateParams.userId;
        if(user){
            userService.detail({id: user}).then(function(response){
                $scope.user = response;
            }).catch(function(error){
                notifications.error(error);
            });
        }
        taskService.get(user).then(function(response){
            $scope.tasks = response;
        }).catch(function(error){
            notifications.error(error);
        });
    };
```

The init function its:

```
        $scope.init = function () {
        $scope.detailCategory({id: $stateParams.categoryId});
        $scope.showAddTask = false;
    };
```

The html its:

```
<div class="all-tasks" ng-init="get()">
<div ng-show="user">
    <p>Tasks from: <strong>{{user.username}}</strong></p>
</div>
<h3 class="margin-bottom-20" ng-show=(tasks|filter:{done:false}).length>Pending</h3>
<div ng-repeat="taskItem in tasks | filter:{done:false}" class="row row-margin button-show">
    <div ng-hide="taskItem.is_editing">
        <div class="inlineBlock">
            <div ng-class="{'checkbox checkbox-circle': !user}">
                <input type="checkbox" ng-hide="user" ng-change="edit(taskItem, true)" ng-model="taskItem.done">
                <label class="lineBreak" ng-click="!user ? taskItem.is_editing = !taskItem.is_editing : false ">{{taskItem.name}}</label>
                <span class="label label-success" ng-if="taskItem.in_progress">In progress</span>
                <div class="label label-default">{{taskItem.category.name}}</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="float-right margin-right-10">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-link btn-no-padding-top" ng-hide="user" ng-click="remove(taskItem, true)"><i class="fa fa-trash text-danger" aria-hidden="true"></i><span class="text-danger"> Delete</span> </button>
            <div class="label label-primary" ng-hide="currentUser.is_superuser">Aggregate <span am-time-ago="taskItem.created_at"></span></div>
            <div class="label label-primary" ng-hide="!currentUser.is_superuser">Agregada el <span>{{taskItem.created_at | amDateFormat:'D [de] MMMM [de] YYYY [a las] h:mm:ss a'}}</span></div>
            <toggle-switch ng-model="taskItem.in_progress" ng-hide="user" class="switch-small switch-success show-hide" ng-change="edit(taskItem, true)" on-label="Si" off-label="No"><toggle-switch>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div ng-if="taskItem.is_editing">
        <form class="form" accept-charset="UTF-8" role="form" name="formEditTask{{taskItem.id}}" novalidate>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-value="taskItem.name" focus-on-show="taskItem.is_editing" ng-model="taskItem.editName" name="task" placeholder="Task" ng-required="true" ng-blur="taskItem.is_editing = !taskItem.is_editing; taskItem.editName=''">
            </div>
            <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" ng-click="edit(taskItem, true)" ng-show="false">Edit</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

When i modify the "if" all works but obviously the user doesn't show in the

Tasks from: **{{user.username}}**

The administrator only see the tasks https://i.stack.imgur.com/ECbEX.png

I need this, like an user:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/VMhxk.png

Comment: It's not really clear what you are asking here.  "the administrator cannot modify the tasks from the users like an user" doesn't really explain much, and you mention modifying an `if` but don't show what modifications you are making to it.

Comment: Well, i need the administrator can add tasks or modify all like the user, at this point the administrator only can see the tasks but the buttons and all the other aren't showed to him

Comment: ok, and what happens when the administrator *tries* to add tasks?  you haven't provided any sample data here, so it's not really easy to recreate your problem.....

Comment: I already added related images, thank you very much

Comment: those screenshots show two totally different views (I would assume that you get to the second one by clicking on one of the tasks from the first, maybe?)...  You still aren't providing a complete picture of what your problem is, and screenshots aren't a replacement for a [mcve] with sample data.

Comment: are you trying to figure out how to make a screen where the administrator can see tasks from *other* users?  this screen you are showing here would only work to show the administrator their own tasks.

Comment: It's the same view bro. That's my bad but well im forgot the validations of the user, that's all the problem. These variable call the user of the tasks so if the admin isn't that user the ng-hide hides the content.  So, just deleting the ng-hide="user" the problem was solved.